# Yield layout in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add a layout to the application layout. I having trouble trying to figure out all the different layout solutions. First I tried just a layout inside a layout because I didn't fully grasp what partials are or if they are layouts also? Maybe I can start with that question. What is the difference between a layout and a partial.

Here is what I have right now. I'm trying to just separate out my header code which has a navigation and some other elements into a separate layout. I want this layout to be on all views. Meaning it should be a layout inside the applications layout along with other views that are been called when their controllers are called. Which is covered in my code with the <%= yield %>. That yeild works but the :header one does not.

**Application Layout**  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>home</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><%= yield(:header) %></div> 
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Header layout**  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% content_for :header %>
    <p>HEADER TEXT</p>
<% end %>
```

Why would the code above not work?

I also saw code like this that I tried but it gave me an error.

```
<%= render layouts/header %>
```

Can someone please explain all these different methods. 
Thanks.

Comment: i had the same problem with yield & content_for:  (I included the do...see below). I'm using Rails 4.  It bothers me that something on the API guide doesn't work even in Rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to separate your header and footer into partials which you would live in the views/layouts folder as '_header.html.erb' and '_footer.html.erb' respectively.

You can then optionally wrap each partial with specific div's which is what you're trying to do with the header (you could do the same with the body too), and it would end up looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>home</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    </div> 
    <%= yield %>

    <div id="footer">
     <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That will do what you want it to do.

Note that 'layouts/header' and 'layouts/footer' have '' around them.

To answer your question on what is the difference between a layout and a partial, well a layout is something that will used throughout your application, such as a consistent header or footer.  A partial can be a layout, but it doesn't have to be, so you can partial specific to other views across your site.

Comment: Thanks jfdimark. "A layout is something that will used throughout your application". This is what I'm using the header for so its throughout the application. According to your answer its a layout I should be using and not a partial? So how would I use a layout inside the application layout like I'm trying to do in my code. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Just save your partial as '_header.html.erb' in the views/layouts folder and then include it in the 'application.html.erb' file as I've shown above.  This really is the definitive guide to learn all about it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html.  Hope you can get it working.

Comment: Got it to work thanks. Still don't understand layout because based on your answer " well a layout is something that will used throughout your application" it makes more sense to use a layout not a partial because I want it to show up throughout my application? Or am I reading your answer wrong.

Comment: I think you're reading it wrong.  If you're partial is in the layouts folder and included in the layouts/application file, then it will be used throughout your application.  I was just trying to explain that a partial _can_ be a layout when used this way, but a partial doesn't _have_ to be a layout, which I'm sure you'll understand soon.  Anyway, glad it's working for you now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% content_for :header do %>
    <p>HEADER TEXT</p>
<% end %>
```

You forgot the `do`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to include this from the same file man. Just put the text and it will render faster regardless.  If you are trying to put default text or something use a ternary.

Comment: oh there was an answer. nm.

Answer (score 0):

So - first - The yield syntax may or may not be correct, but I've never seen it, and I don't like it. I only ever call yield once in a file.

If you want to render a header in your application template file, that's certainly possible - my advice would be to place it in your template file directly - after all, that's what template files are for. If you want to completely encapsulate your header for some reason or another in seperate files, what you need is partials. You're going to do something like this:

```
<body>
    <%= render :partial => "shared/header" %>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
```

Which will render your header content, stored in /shared/_header.html.erb into the layout here.

Check out [this guide here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for more info

Comment: Where is the /shared/ folder meant to be?

Comment: Also do you need to wrap the html code in the _header.html.erb file with <% %> tag?

Comment: The shared folder should be in your views folder, so /app/views/shared/.

As for wrapping - well, the _header.html.erb is a view, just like any other, and should be written as one.

Comment: Not rails 4 compatible btw.